# Passing variable to.exe in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

After decalring vaiables. How do I pass it to a .exe? My code below does not work.

```
DECLARE @ODBCConn varchar(10)
SET @ODBCConn = 'TestDb'

EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell '"C:\tmt.exe"' + @ODBCConn
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't perform concatenation when passing a parameter into a stored procedure; the parameter must be a *value*, and not an *expression* that would result in a value...

instead, perform the concatenation before calling:

```
DECLARE @ODBCConn varchar(10)
SET @ODBCConn = 'TestDb'

DECLARE @Cmd varchar(500)
SET @Cmd = '"C:\tmt.exe" ' + @ODBCConn

EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell @Cmd
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are just missing a space after the exe name.

```
EXECUTE master..xp_cmdshell '"C:\tmt.exe "' + @ODBCConn
```